# Add sequential numbering into HTML files

Tags: batch, automation, html, numbering

I have bunch of HTML and image files. HTML files are named page1.html, page2.html, page3.html etc. Images are named the same way image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg etc. Every HTML file has one link to an image file

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="">
```

and this link should point to the image file with same number as the HTML file. How can I add sequential numbering to HTML files so that from page1.html there is link to image1.jpg and so on?
Is there some program (for Windows) or can I use command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell is a great solution for this.

```
Set-Location "C:\htmlfiles"

# for each html file
gci *.html | % {

    # select the number from the filename
    $number = $_.BaseName -replace '\D+(\d+)','$1'

    # prepare the new image file name
    $newImageName = 'image' + $number + '.jpg'

    # get the content of the html file and replace the old image name with the new name
    (gc $_).Replace('image.jpg',$newImageName) | sc $_

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that you can find software that can do this as it is something very specific. You could create a custom `PowerShell` script to do it but it won't be very easy if you are not used to `PowerShell`

I think the best option you have is to separate the HTML and images in folders named XXXX1, XXXX2 and inside every folder just have the HTML file without numbers and the image without numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I know you tagged the question [batch](/questions/tagged/batch),
but you also tagged it [automation](/questions/tagged/automation), so ...

If you have access to GNU/Unix tools
(including Windows Subsystem for Linux or Linux Subsystem on Windows
(or whatever it’s called), Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, Cygwin, etc.)
you can do this fairly easily: 
Set `dir` to the name of the directory where the files are
(can be `"."`) and execute

```
for file in "$dir"/page*.html
do
    basename=${file%.html}
    number=${basename#$dir/page}
    sed -i "s/<img src=\"image.jpg\" alt=\"\">/<img src=\"image$number.jpg\" alt=\"\">/" "$file"
done
```

This looks at *all* files in the directory
whose names begin with `page` and end with `.html`,
extracts whatever lies between (which should be the file number),
and edits the `<img>` element to change the image filename.