# Read duration of mp3 file and write it in a text file with Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch, automation, mp3

This is a follow-up question to this older [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1277077/add-sequential-numbering-into-html-files). This time I have bunch of mp3 and smil files in one folder. Both file types are named the same way and mp3 file is paired to smil file with the same name. For example, file-1.mp3 and file-1.smil are a pair. I need to write duration of the mp3 file to its smil file in this kind of form "00:00:00.000". For example,
`clipEnd="0:01:15.123"`.

Is this possible with Powershell using the previous code from the older question?

```
Set-Location "C:\htmlfiles"

# for each html file
gci *.html | % {

    # select the number from the filename
    $number = $_.BaseName -replace '\D+(\d+)','$1'

    # prepare the new image file name
    $newImageName = 'image' + $number + '.jpg'

    # get the content of the html file and replace the old image name with the new name
    (gc $_).Replace('image.jpg',$newImageName) | sc $_

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a built in windows function for this sox should make it possible for you to extract this info rather easy.

http://sox.sourceforge.net/

Here is an example to extract from wave but the it should be the same with mp3.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534372/get-length-of-wav-from-sox-output

But I assume there might be better ways to do this but this would be one path that would support a huge amount of file formats and not just mp3.

Comment: The "built-on" way would be to use [GetDetailsOf](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-getdetailsof) but the length returned  is a formatted string with no milliseconds available.